# Clarifying "don't like you because" or "like you not because"

Tags: negation

'I don't like you because you have money', this sentence is a little logically weird for me, though I know it conveys the same meaning of the sentence 'I like you not because you have money'. Can I directly say the second one instead of the first?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, both sentences seem unsuitable. I suggest this sentence: "*Money is not the reason that I like you*". I just guess the meaning of your sentences. Hope that it will be correct per your intent.

Answer (score 0):

They mean different things. In:

> I don't like you because you have money.

"you" has money but isn't liked by "I".

> I like you not because you have money

is more of a sentence fragment or at least an incomplete thought.

> I like you not because you have money, but because you are kind and considerate.

Without the explanation, you could also use:

> I like you *but* not because you have money.

In either of these examples, "I" likes "you", but the reason is not the money "you" has, but another reason.